# Failed to manually clean-up svn, now "end of file" is found

Tags: svn

So, I ran `svn co`, but the computer ran out of memory. This was a while back, but, as a result, not everything got saved. I tried to manually delete the files and recommit, and everything seemd fine.

But now, when I try to check out the repository, I get a message which says

```
svn: Can't read file 'BLAHBLAH/db/revs/0/57': End of file found
```

That worries me. I'm not sure if I'm checking everything out correctly or not. I'd delete the repository and start over, but I'd like to save the change history on these files.

Any thoughts on how I can clean up this mess?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered checking out an earlier version rather than the latest? May be you can try to update it step-by-step until the most recent one. At each step recompile your project to check for errors and correct them.

Comment: Every revision from 57 upwards includes that message in the checkout. Are you suggesting that I check out each version and then recommit to a new repository? I think it might be difficult to see what files, if any, would be missing because it is the nature of the repository to change over time. Does SVN have any built in functionality for trying to sort this sort of thing out?

Comment: Try with 56. Compile it. Then try to update to 57. Compile it. Etc... If svn won't let you go higher than 57, then try with a backup at 56 and redo the work you did above 56. If you have patches, this is great, else it is tedious. Check this too: http://devpinoy.org/blogs/joeycalisay/archive/2006/07/12/SubversionTmpFile.aspx

Comment: Compiling isn't an option for verification since this is a client-server program with a number of scripts. If there was a way to revert all the files backwards from the current checked-out version to a previous version then I could save change back until the point where the SVN is corrupted.

Comment: @Richard There is a revert function in SVN, but if it does not work because your repository is corrupted, may be you can try to check-out an earlier revision (non corrupted), export the content of this checkout in a separate directory (to dodge/remove .svn files), then copy the older valid files from this export to into your corrupted check-out.